# Printing envelopes for mailing with beamer presentation class

Tags: geometry, printing, paper-size

I was able to print several U.S. #10 business letter envelopes 4⅛”×9½” (10.4cm×24.1cm) for mailing with more or less the code I have included below, but the `beamer` documentclass does not seem to respect the choice of papersize, and the `geometry` package appears incompatible with this documentclass and generates various "clash" warnings and error messages.

Envelopes of course are printed landscape mode, like the presentation slides, and at least on my printer, which I assume is not unusual, with the printable area vertically centered and right-justified, because the envelopes are loaded in with right edge leading.

I don't really think envelopes for mailing are that special of a case, either, for presentation slides. I basically just want to know the best way of specifying a custom papersize for presentation slides.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{minipage-marginpar}
\usetheme{default}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}~\\[1.25in]
Address 1\\
123 Main Street\\
City, State ZIP
\end{minipage}\linebreak
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}~\\[1.25in]
Address 2\\
Back Alley 2\,A\\
Postcode City, Country  
\end{minipage}\linebreak
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, the `beamer` class was designed for presentations, not for envelopes. It defines some special settings to this end, as you already noted. But, you can essentially use any other basic class, such as `article`, and set the page size (landscape as well) with the `geometry` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably not use the `beamer` class since it is not made for typesetting envelopes. In section 8.3 of the [`beamer`  manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), apart from stating a row of possible frame size options (none of which fits a letter envelope format), it says:

> Aside from using these options, you should refrain from changing the “paper size.”

However, you can essentially use any other basic document class and set the paper size and margins using the `geometry` package. For example like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[
    paperheight=4.125in, 
    paperwidth=9.5in,
    left=0.5in,
    right=0.5in,
    top=0.625in,
    bottom=0.625in
]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t][0.3\paperheight]{0.5\paperwidth}
\small
Return address \\
Some street \\
Some town, some ZIP code
\end{minipage}

\vspace*{.5in}
\hspace*{3in}
\begin{minipage}{3in}
\large
Delivery address \\
Some street \\
Some town, some ZIP code
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you're right on, because the "article" class probably is the most adaptable and customizable with extra packages -- so you just specify a pagestyle empty, skip the title and abstract, set the papersize and margins -- and it's pretty much a blank slate like any word processor. With the beamer class, I am nonetheless able specify the papersize when printing, and "fit to page" when printing.

Comment: But what if I do want a beamer class style presentation, say 11"x17" posterboard or 5"x7" index card size etc.? Or flash cards printed on both sides, etc.?

Comment: Well, `beamer` loads the `geometry` package anyways. So, you actually *can* set another paper size using `\geometry{papersize={7in,5in}}` for example. It is just not recommended. And for envelopes, I would really not use the `beamer` class. It is just too big and comes with too much functionality for such a simple task.

Comment: There's people who work in sales